# Is it possible to recover the ca.crt and ca.key after i deleted them?

Tags: openvpn, vpn, certificates

I accidentally removed my OpenVPN `ca.crt`, `ca.key`, `server.crt` and `server.key` with the `./clean-all` command. I didn't know that the server config (currently also the "signing machine") pointed to the `easy-rsa/keys` directory instead of to the `certificates` folder as we do on the clients. (i know its stupid to not check this first but that is to late now)

For some reason stay the already connected devices still connected. I can also connect new clients with the existing (old/currently deployed) certificates. **I think this is because i did not restart the vpn service yet, isn't it?** (I don't dare to restart the service now because i'm scared I can't access the clients anymore)

**Is there a way to get my `ca.key` so I can generate a new `server.crt` and `server.key`?** (Or maybe so get the `server.x` back as well). I still have the `ca.crt` as its available on the clients.

**When i cant get my `ca.key` back, what is the best way to solve my issue?** I suppose i need to

1. generate a new `ca.crt` and `ca.key`
2. generate a new server certificate
3. generate new client certificates
4. distribute the new (client) certificates to the clients (as i can still reach them via VPN now)
5. restart the VPN service on the clients (so they use the new certificate)
6. restart the VPN service on the server so the new certificates become active (when i forgot a client, its "lost" from now on?)

It is important that i do not "lose" clients as i need to drive a few hours to get access to some of the clients!

Comment: Do you have a recent backup?

Comment: No unfortunately i don't have any backup else i had already recover them from the backup. I started with my job this week and took over the whole IT management (as the previous ICT employee left the company) and there are backup servers but this was never back-upped ...

Comment: If you are still connected, then (as you suggest) creating new keys may be the best option.

Comment: Ok, is it true that the clients are still connected because i did not restart the service? so when i restart the service they will lose connection? -- even when i'm happy with it,i don't understand why they are still connected as the server certificate does not exist anymore on the location of the server.conf. I suppose this means the cert. is somewhere loaded or something?

Comment: From [RSA Key Management](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/rsa-key-management/): *"# WARNING: clean-all will do a `rm -rf` on this directory so make sure you define it correctly!"* - at least it's clear the files are gone and not archived somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a solution to get my CA.crt back an decided to deploy new certificates as the connections are currently still alive. I setup an test environment and tested the workflow described below. After that i used that workflow for the live connections as wel and worked fine!

1. First generated all the certificates on the "CA Machine" (CA, Server and Client certificates)
2. Deployed the certificates to all the clients and made sure that the configs where correct so they use the new certificates
3. Restart the OpenVPN service on each client (individually) and make sure there are no "open connections" on the OpenVPN server anymore
4. Replace the OpenVPN server certificate and restart the OpenVPN service on the OpenVPN server

Make sure you don't restart any service before exchanging the new certificates and checking the configs. Its important that the OpenVPN server service is not restarted before all clients have their new certificates and the services on the clients are restarted.

Now i got back all my client connections with the new certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If I get time, I can try doing this on a spare raspberry pi and see.  But, failing that,  the first thing I'd do is make sure you can remote into the clients computers, either with teamviewer or something like that,  this way you end up having to blow everything away and start fresh, you can remote into them.